# values that are equal as characters but not equal as other type in R

Tags: r

Looking at the source of the function `factor`, I see this code:

```
  if (missing(levels)) {
    y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
    ind <- sort.list(y)
    y <- as.character(y)
    levels <- unique(y[ind])
}
```

At first glance it was seem to me the use of `unique` function in the last line is unnecessary. So I was searching for 2 values, let's call them `v1` and `v2` that `v1 == v2` returns FALSE, but `as.character(v1) == as.character(v2)` returns TRUE. but could not find them so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line of code in `factor()` is to deal with matrix because `unique()` removes duplicate **ROWS** when the argument is matrix.

```
x <- matrix(rep(1:5, 2), nrow=5)

y <- unique(x)       # In this example, unique(x) remove nothing from x
ind <- sort.list(y)
y <- as.character(y)
levels1 <- unique(y[ind])
levels2 <- y[ind]

levels1 # [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
levels2 # [1] "1" "1" "2" "2" "3" "3" "4" "4" "5" "5"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the motivation for the line of code in `factor`, but here is one example of "values that are equal as characters but not equal as other type"

```
a <- 1-1e-16
b <- 1-1e-17
a==b; as.character(a)==as.character(b)
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
```